# Three JS how to render the xyz axis over all the models inside a scene?

Tags: three.js, axis, scene

Currently I want to render the axis over the cube (rather than through it).  But I can't figure out a way to do that.  Does any one know how to render the axis lines over the cube module?  Thanks.

Have provided the JS code below. 
The cube will be rendered in **scene** and axis lines will be rendered in **fscene**.  (The axis lines rendered in **fscene** is supposed to cover the cube which rendered in **scene**)

```
    var container, stats;

    var camera, scene, fscene, renderer;

    var cube, plane;

    function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 999999 );
        camera.position.y = 5;
        camera.position.z = 5;
        camera.position.x = 4;
        camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        fscene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Cube

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

        for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {

            geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( 0xcccccc * i );

        }

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );
        cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add(cube);

        addAxis();

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.autoClear = false;
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        animate();
    }


    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        renderer.render(fscene, camera);
    }

    function addAxis() {
        var sceneSize = 9000;
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [sceneSize, 0, 0], color: 0xff0000, scene: scene });
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [-sceneSize, 0, 0], color: 0xff0000, dashed: true, scene: scene });
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [0, sceneSize, 0], color: 0x00ff00, scene: scene });
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [0, -sceneSize, 0], color: 0x00ff00, dashed: true, scene: scene });
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [0, 0, sceneSize], color: 0x0000ff, scene: scene });
        line({ begin: [0, 0, 0], end: [0, 0, -sceneSize], color: 0x0000ff, dashed: true, scene: scene });
    }

    function line(cfg){
        var p = cfg.begin;
        var q = cfg.end;
        if (cfg.color) {
            cfg.colorb = cfg.colorb || cfg.color;
            cfg.colore = cfg.colore || cfg.color;
        }
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var material = cfg.dashed ? new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({ linewidth: 1, color: cfg.color, dashSize: 1, gapSize: 1, depthWrite:false }) : new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, depthWrite:false });
        var cp = new THREE.Color(cfg.colorb);
        var cq = new THREE.Color(cfg.colore);

        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(p[0], p[1], p[2]));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(q[0], q[1], q[2]));
        geometry.colors.push(cp,cq);
        geometry.computeLineDistances();

        var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material, THREE.LinePieces);
        fscene.add(line);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TransformControls.js contains the code that might help you.
**depthTest** should be set to **false** and **transparent** should be set to **true**.